# Getting repeated lines with awk in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, text-processing

I'm trying to know which are the lines that are repeated X times in a text file, and I'm using `awk` but I see that `awk` in my command, not work with lines that begin with the same characters or words. That is, does not recognize the full line individually.

Using this command I try to get the lines that are repeated 3 times:

```
 awk '++A[$1]==3' ./textfile > ./log
```

Comment: You are using `$1` which is the first field of the line. If you want the whole line you want to use `$0`. Also this will trigger on any line that has at least three copies in the file and not only exactly three copies in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need hopefully:

```
awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(i in a){if(a[i]==3)print i}}' File
```

Increment array `a` with the line(`$0`) as index for each line. In the end, for each index (`$0`), check if the count(`a[i]` which is the original `a[$0]`) equals `3`. If so, print the line (`i` which is the original `$0` / line). Hope it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

This returns lines repeated 3 times but adds a space at the beginning of each 3x-repeated line:

```
sort ./textfile | uniq -c | awk '$1 == 3 {$1 = ""; print}' > ./log
```